# Keeping fondue warm

Tags: equipment, temperature, fondue

It’s chilly out. Fondue time!

I have no problem making fondue, but keeping it warm for my guests has presented a little bit of a problem.  My proposed solution is to scoop the fondue into an enameled cast iron pot on a trivet, warmed by a tea candle or two.

Do you think this would keep my fondue at the right consistency?

Comment: What kind of fondue are you asking about? The required temperature is vastly different between e.g. chocolate and oil.

Comment: Are you taking about outside or indoor use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a setup similar to what you're proposing, except made for fondues. It works very well, except it is set up for 4 tea candles. 1 or 2 is not sufficient unless you have a very small pot or eat very quickly. 4 candles keeps it at the right temperature for ~1.5 hours. Using a cast iron pot is also optimal since they retain heat so well. If you're preparing a fondue fairly quickly I would recommend preheating the pot in the oven to make sure it's warm through before starting.

Answer (score 2):

A small fuel burner like this would work great:

[https://www.amazon.com/Swissmar-KF-63011-Fondue-Burner/dp/B000UM2X76](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000UM2X76)

Both the implement and the fuel are pretty cheap.

Otherwise a portable burner, either electric or gas is great and you can use your regular pots and pans:

[https://www.amazon.com/Courant-Electric-Countertop-Hotplate-Portable/dp/B07CZ67Y7Y/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CZ67Y7Y)

If you eat a lot of fondue, a dedicated fondue maker is my implement of choice:

[https://www.amazon.com/Cuisinart-CFO-3SS-Electric-Fondue-Maker/dp/B00018RR48](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00018RR48)

Gas ones are pretty common in thrift shops too.